# Reference for Project from Nuget or GitHub Source?

Tags: c#, prism

I should use a nuget package or a github source for reference on my project?
For example, I am using libraries like Template10 and Prism 6, and I started using them, when they did not exist on nuget, then I was using their github source to reference, but now both are on nuget, do I should migrate the references for nuget? or not?

Comment: Its a matter of opinion, but for the ease of updating and not having to sync repo's, I'd prefer the Nuget packages over forking (which is what I assume you are doing, if you are just downloading the code and replacing it periodically, then definitely ditch that method).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is there some way you can reference a git project directly in Visual Studio? Are you even using visual studio? Also your question is too subjective - please clarify what you are trying to achieve, e.g. possibly. 'is it easier to maintain my .NET Visual Studio project by doing x instead of y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Switch to NuGet packages for ease of use, stick with the source if you want to tweak it.

You can indeed clone the source of GitHub, build it yourself and add the dlls, or just add the complete projects to your own solution. It's necessary if you want to use a certain library before it's available on NuGet (or through another way as like e.g. a vsix installer). But it's a lot of work to keep that code in sync with new versions (and you're not always sure the version you just cloned is a stable version).

However there is a reason for the existence of NuGet, and that's ease of use. You pick a package version and work against that, you're the one deciding when/if you'll update to a new version of the package. You're 100% sure that the version you're using is working as intended (of course bugs do exist :)). You basically trust the experience of the library creators with which they decide when the code is stable enough to give a public release.

So except for when you're tweaking the library's source yourself, I would suggest to use the NuGet package for ease of use.

Comment: I would stick with NuGet. It's easier to use and maintain. Only need to reference the source on GitHub/other if you need to tweak the source or if its not available on NuGet.